# xsl : how to mix identity transformation and custom rules?

Tags: xslt

I got a xml (catalog of books with covers) for which I created a xsl that displays books as if they were on a bookshelves.

Now I want to allow the display of the underlying xml.
I thought of showing/hiding a textarea in which I'd have written the xml using a identity rule.

How can I do it? I mean I already wrote rule for "/" and descendants ("books", "authors"), if I add a identity rule it would be fine till it calls itself but when one of my custom rule will match I'll start to output the text associated with the custom rule.

EDIT

As suggested by Martin Honnen and Michael Kay, the solution was to use mode.

```
<xsl:template match="/"> 
 <html> 
  <body> 
  ...
  <xsl:apply-templates select="foo"" /> 
  ...
  <textarea>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//*"          mode="SERIALIZE" />
  </textarea>
  </body> 
 </html> 
</xsl:template>

<!-- identity transform  -->
<xsl:template match="/ | @* | node()"          mode="SERIALIZE" >
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"    mode="SERIALIZE" />
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Note the mode="SERIALIZE" :
  when calling apply templates,
  in the definition of the identity template and
  inside it when calling itself recursively.

Comment: It would help alot if you showed a sample of your XML, the XSLT you currently have, and the output you expect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show the markup of an input node you need to serialize it. In XSLT 3 with XPath 3.1 support you can do that using the `serialize` function e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="book" mode="show">
  <pre>
    <xsl:value-of select="serialize(.)"/>
  </pre>
</xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rM4/1 has an example using XSLT 3 and the `serialize` function to output the markup of a `book` input element inside of a HTML `pre` result element.

With earlier versions of XSLT you need to check whether your XSLT processor provides or supports an extension function or you need to use XSLT to serialize a node, there I would suggest to rely on existing libraries like http://lenzconsulting.com/xml-to-string/xml-to-string.xsl, documented at http://lenzconsulting.com/xml-to-string/, as doing it right with namespaces and escaping is a complex task such a library does better than quick attempts to write a template for element and attribute nodes to produce some tags.

On the other hand, if you really want to use a HTML textarea, given that its content model is text, you might get way with outputting the element inside the textara element e.g. `<textarea><xsl:copy-of select="."/></textarea>` or if you prefer to push it through an identity transformation. The right tool with XSLT to separate two templates for the same matched node(s) is to use a named `mode` for at least one template. In XSLT 1.0 you would then need to set up the identity transformation template also for that mode, in XSLT 2 you can change the identity transformation template to use `mode="#all"` on `xsl:template` and `mode="#current"` on the `xsl:apply-templates` inside.

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiJ2/1 has an example which simply copies the `book` element through as content of the HTML textarea element with `<xsl:copy-of select="."/>` and browsers seem to handle that fine to display the XML markup.

Answer (score 1):

The way to mix two different ways of processing the same nodes is to use modes. You can define two different modes of processing by attaching different `mode` attributes to the template rules, and you can initiate processing in a particular mode by adding a `mode` attribute to the `xsl:apply-templates` instruction.